# pushMiddleware through service provider not executing the middleware globally

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on package to add global middleware, I used kernel pushMiddleware method through the service provider, but it's not executing, even it's working when using appendMiddlewareToGroup('web', Middleware) method, but I need it global.

```
<?php

namespace UseTransaction;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use UseTransaction\Middlewares\UseTransactionMiddleware;

class UseTransactionProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Kernel $kernel)
    {
        $kernel->pushMiddleware(UseTransactionMiddleware::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this path for Kernel

```
\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel $kernel
```